# python np.nan and '==' & 'is'

Tags: python, identity, equality

When I check for equality and identity of Python operands e.g. `a = []; b = a` I get this:

```
a == b => True
a is b => True
```

and I understand it.

so, why I am getting diff result with np.nan?:

```
a = np.nan; b = a 
a == b => False
a is b => True
```

?

Answer (score 7):

Because `NaN` is never equal to *anything* else, and
we use `==` for performing an **equality** comparison.

On the other hand the *object* used to represent `NaN` is identical to itself, because `is` is used for doing an **identity** comparison.

Comment: Interesting. (+1) I tried a similar experiment with `None` instead of `np.nan`. Turns out that `a = None; b = a; print (a == b)` prints `True`.

Comment: Can you explain to me the difference between an equality and an identity comparison?

Comment: @Psychotechnopath Equality: two objects with the same _value_, not necessarily the same object. Identity: the exact, same object.

Comment: So basically NaN == NaN returns False because it is never equal to anything else, but  all np.nan's do point to the same object, and thus np.nan is np.nan returns True? 

This is exactly the opposite way it is in normal objects (e.g. `a = [1,2,3]` `c = [1,2,3]`  `a ==c` returns `True` whereas `a is c` returns `False`

Comment: @Psychotechnopath NaN is a special case. Nothing is equal to NaN, ever: not even NaN itself. `np.nan == np.nan` is `False`, even though `np.nan is np.nan` is `True`.

Comment: yes but `np.nan is np.nan` returns True, is that because they point to the same object?

Comment: You said it yourself

Comment: @ÓscarLópez get it now then =) TYVM for quick response!